# Finding a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a field $\mathbb{F}_{2} = \{0,1\}$ where addition and multiplication are defined by $0 + 0 = 1 + 1 = 0, 0 + 1 = 1 + 0 = 1$ and $0\cdot0 = 0\cdot1 = 1\cdot0 = 0$ and $1\cdot1=1$.

The problem is to construct a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}[x_{1}...x_{n}]$ such that it vanishes for every point in $\mathbb{F}^3$.

My solution is simply.

$\prod x_{i} + \prod x_{i}$ .

The solution manual gives a different answer. I want to check if my solution is correct or if there is anything I have missed out.

Comment: Your solution is correct. What does the manual give you as the solution?

Comment: Your polynomial is the zero polynomial, a trivial solution, which may be why the solution manual doesn't approve of it. On the other hand, the polynomial $x^2-x$ vanishes for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_2$. Can you use that to give a non-zero polynomial in three variables that vanishes at all the inputs from $\Bbb{F}_2^3$?

Comment: Please edit your post to tell us what solution your manual gives, and whether you understand it.